# Updating ps_product table fields show_price and available_for_order in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Updating ps_product table fields show_price and available_for_order in Prestashop 1.6 using these two queries produces inconsistencies in the database?

```
UPDATE `ps_product` SET `show_price`=1, `available_for_order`=1 WHERE id_product = xxxxxxxxxx;
UPDATE `ps_product_shop` SET `show_price`=1, available_for_order=1 WHERE id_product = xxxxxxxxxx;
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You do it in your module?

Comment: I use these two queries to update both fields. I have set up a single store, not a multi-store prestashop. Thanks